# How to deploy a SpringBoot webapp: war or jar?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

A Spring Boot server application is fairly simple to set up using Maven. But I can't seem to figure out why I'm having trouble using it for a webapp and I can't find clear documentation on how to do what I am trying to. Perhaps, I'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Normally, one would build a war and deploy it into a standalone started Tomcat instance. My understanding is that SpringBoot let's you have an embedded tomcat instance. Then you start the server from the jar using the `java -jar /path/to/target/springbootapp.jar`

But when I add webapp contents, how do I deploy it? Do I have to change my `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to `<packaging>war</packaging>`? or can I still use the jar? If I do change it war, then how do I start it?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Thanks@JB Nizet, that was helpful! In my case, I am using a webjar, but I dont see the contents of that webjar anywhere in the target folder or classpath or output jar. Also when I go to localhost:8080/context/ or localhost:8080/context/index.html, etc no content is served. Perhaps I have to configure a controller for the webapp?

Comment: ahah! I found out how to get to the index.html file of the webjar, but still don't see the sources that got pulled in. I could load the webjar at: localhost:8080/{webjar artifactId}/{version}/index.html

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging  Also for WAR http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: Another suggestion would be to look at Spring Initializer to build the correct structure for you.  https://start.spring.io/  Spring boot does not really use the webapp directory structure anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already found answer through above comments and by yourself. 
Here some summary

Packaging should be war on pom.xml to include static file under WEB-INF.

Below is just example

**pom.xml**

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables-plugins</artifactId>
        <version>ca6ec50</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can run from command line also with specifying launcher (JarLauncher / WarLauncher)

**command line**

```
java -cp your-target.war;some-dependency.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

Also you can configure the path of resource like webjars by setting up resourceHandlerRegistry like below

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.your.spring.controller")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/images/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/images/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/css/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/js/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/js/");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Now your jsp file can have the path for the static content inside webjar like below

**On jsp file**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/jquery-ui-themes/1.11.3/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/datatables/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/datatables-plugins/ca6ec50/integration/foundation/dataTables.foundation.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery-ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/datatables/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/datatables-plugins/ca6ec50/integration/foundation/dataTables.foundation.js"></script>
```